# php regular expression to replace "some words" with a link tag, but should exclude "some words" inside link tags

Tags: php, regex

I have html content stored in a database table. in that html content I want to replace "SOME WORDS" with a link tag. But if "SOME WORDS" is already inside a link tag i should omit them..

e.g.
**The content**

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor SOME WORDS, consectetur adipiscing elit. <a href="http://example.com">SOME WORDS</a> elementum pharetra velit at cursus. Quisque blandit, nibh at eleifend ullamcorper</p>
```

**The output should be**

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor <a href="http://someurl">SOME WORDS</a>, consectetur adipiscing elit. <a href="http://example.com">SOME WORDS</a> elementum pharetra velit at cursus. Quisque blandit, nibh at eleifend ullamcorper</p>
```

as you can see, it should exclude existing link texts when replacing.

Some guidance to get in to the right track is very much appreciated.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions, use a HTML parser such as domdocument

Comment: Try - http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php - and - http://weblogtoolscollection.com/regex/regex.php - and some other crap.

Comment: Remember that girl from the ring? She tried to use regular expressions to process HTML too, and see what happened to her!

Comment: @Ninearts Being new to anything is no excuse. Unless the situation is going back in time and turning into a dinosaur then you can do some research. Most of the time typing the 'titles' into Google deliver the answers.

Comment: @Jack... Hilarious! But thought provoking!

Comment: @Ninearts, forgive my compatriots for their undue bluntness.  I do suggest you take a shot at it yourself.  The tutorial Qoop linked doesn't seem *too* horrible.  Once you have a better understanding of what you don't know, and are able to show us a starting point, we'll be more able to actually help you get from that starting point towards the goal.

Comment: @Qoop that's a bit harsh, this is not fight club.

Comment: @Jack, sorry about that. It just becomes infuriating. I have learned everything I know from random crap I gained of the internet so I find it irritating when people can't find what I find people asking for basic information. This, however, is beyond me... so I'm clearly a cock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you could solve it using `DOMDocument` instead of regular expressions:

```
$contents = <<<EOS
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor SOME WORDS, consectetur adipiscing elit. <a href="http://example.com">SOME WORDS</a> elementum pharetra velit at cursus. Quisque blandit, nibh at eleifend ullamcorper</p>
EOS;

$doc = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($contents);
libxml_clear_errors();

$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);

// find all text nodes
foreach ($xp->query('//text()') as $node) {
        // make sure it's not inside an anchor
        if ($node->parentNode->nodeName !== 'a') {
                $node->nodeValue = str_replace(
                    'SOME WORDS', 
                    'SOME OTHER WORDS', 
                    $node->nodeValue
                );
        }
}
// DOMDocument creates a full document and puts your fragment inside a body tag
// So we enumerate the children and save their HTML representation
$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
foreach ($body->childNodes as $node) {
        echo $doc->saveHTML($node);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple regex will only work if it's the exact phrase and inside the link without any other symbols or words. You could iterate through all occurrences of `SOME WORDS` to see if they are inside a link by calculating the amount of times there was an opening and closing link tag before the occurrence. Try this code:

```
$str = '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor SOME WORDS, consectetur adipiscing elit. <a href="http://example.com">SOME WORDS</a> elementum pharetra velit at cursus. Quisque blandit, nibh at eleifend ullamcorper</p>';
echo 'Before:' . $str;
$str_lc = strtolower($str);
$phrase = 'SOME WORDS';
$link = '<a href="http://someurl">SOME WORDS</a>';
$offset = 0;
while($position = strpos($str, $phrase, $offset))
{
    if (substr_count($str_lc, "<a", 0, $position) <= substr_count($str_lc, "</a>", 0, $position)) {
        $str = substr_replace($str, $link, $position, strlen($phrase));
        $str_lc = strtolower($str);
        $offset = $position + strlen($link) - strlen($phrase);
    } else {
        $offset = $position + 1;
    }
}
echo 'After:' . $str;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have room for 3 lines this would be a safe bet:

```
$text=preg_replace('~<a(.*)(SOME WORDS)(.*)</a>~','<a$1PLACEHOLDER$3</a>',$text);
$text=preg_replace('~SOME WORDS~','REPLACEMENT WORDS',$text);
$text=preg_replace('~PLACEHOLDER~','SOME WORDS',$text);
```

It will use a PLACEHOLDER text/tag/whatever so you don't replace a link contents (in case there is one).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

Just check in the regex if SOME WORDS is surrounded by tags

```
preg_replace('/[^>]SOME WORDS[^<]/','<a href="http://someurl">SOME WORDS</a>',$str);
```

Comment: this will break at something like: <a href="#">here are SOME WORDS for you</a>